# How can I add a JS function to make all numbers including INPUT fields show the THOUSAND SEPARATOR?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

Can you please have a look at this code and advise how can I make all numbers appear with the thousand separator "," on all numbers including when users input new numbers in the input fields. the code can be seen on

https://jsfiddle.net/moeadas/53wqcmg6/29/

I'm not a developer but trying to work on some small projects to enhance my skills so I'm sure you will see the code poorly written but its working fine for me :-)

Many thanks for your support.

here is the JS code as well

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }

  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("CreativeAcquisitions").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}


function calcule2(){

var i=0; for (i=0;i<= 50;i++) {calcule();}} 

function calcule(){ 

    CreativeAcquisitions.B28.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B17.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B19.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B21.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B23.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B25.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B52.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B4.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B6.value)) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D81.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B55.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B4.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B6.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B56.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B28.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B66.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B200.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B67.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B56.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B68.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B36.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B37.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B38.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B39.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B40.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B69.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B41.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B70.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B200.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B46.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B71.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B200.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B47.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B72.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B66.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B68.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B70.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B69.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B71.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B76.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B17.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D76.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B76.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C76.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B77.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B19.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D77.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B77.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C77.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B78.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B21.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D78.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B78.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C78.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B79.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B23.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D79.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B79.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C79.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B80.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B25.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D80.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B80.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C80.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B81.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B76.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B77.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B78.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B79.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B80.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D81.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D76.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D77.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D78.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D79.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D80.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B91.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B36.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B92.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B37.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B93.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B38.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B94.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B39.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B95.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B40.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B96.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B52.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B46.value)) /100;

  CreativeAcquisitions.B97.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B41.value);


  CreativeAcquisitions.B98.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B91.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B92.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B93.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B94.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B95.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B96.value)+  parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B97.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.C98.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C91.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C92.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C93.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C94.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C95.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C96.value) +  parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C97.value);

  CreativeAcquisitions.B101.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B4.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B105.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B101.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B103.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B107.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C98.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B108.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B101.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B105.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B107.value);
}
```

Comment: You need to use event handlers. For INPUT fields, consider events such as on change, key-up, and/or blur. For static fields, they can be formatted at the time the text is set. You might be able to find a js library that does it for you.

Comment: Have a look at this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat  Sadly there's no magic "do this for all numbers everywhere" setting that you can trigger.

Comment: Interesting. Will have a look. Thank you my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I'm selecting all inputs with type text, so you should add a certain class to the inputs that you want to apply the thousand separator on for example `class="thousand-sep"` and select the inputs with that class instead, to avoid getting invalid input values if the input is not a valid number(in your case it's ok because all inputs are for numbers although you could even set the type to number instead).

```js
//////////Newcode///////////////////////////
function milesIt(num) {
  return Math.floor(num).toString().split("").reverse().map((n, i, a) =>
   (i + 1) % 3 === 0 && i + 1 != a.length && "." + n || n).reverse().join("");
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text']");
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  //change the values to include the thousand separator each time the user changes an input
  input.onchange = function(e) {
    inputs.forEach(function(inp) {
      inp.value = inp.value.replace(/[.]/g, '');
    });
    calcule2();
    inputs.forEach(function(inp) {
      inp.value = milesIt(inp.value);
    });
    //e.target.value = milesIt(e.target.value.replace(/[.]/g, ''));
  }
  //change the values of the inputs at the beginning, although you could write them as HTML with the thousand separator values in the source code
  input.value = milesIt(input.value);
});
////////////////////////////////////////////
  
 
 
 var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("CreativeAcquisitions").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}





function calcule2(){

var i=0; for (i=0;i<= 50;i++) {calcule();}} 

function calcule(){ 

    CreativeAcquisitions.B28.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B17.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B19.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B21.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B23.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B25.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B52.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B4.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B6.value)) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D81.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B55.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B4.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B6.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B56.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B28.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B66.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B200.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B67.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B56.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B68.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B36.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B37.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B38.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B39.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B40.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B69.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B41.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B70.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B200.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B46.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B71.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B200.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B47.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B72.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B66.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B68.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B70.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B69.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B71.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B76.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B17.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D76.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B76.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C76.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B77.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B19.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D77.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B77.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C77.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B78.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B21.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D78.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B78.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C78.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B79.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B23.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D79.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B79.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C79.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B80.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B25.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D80.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B80.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C80.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B81.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B76.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B77.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B78.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B79.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B80.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.D81.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D76.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D77.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D78.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D79.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.D80.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B91.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B36.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B92.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B37.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B93.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B38.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B94.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B39.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B95.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B40.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B96.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B52.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B46.value)) /100;
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B97.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B41.value);
 
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B98.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B91.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B92.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B93.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B94.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B95.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B96.value)+  parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B97.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.C98.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C91.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C92.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C93.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C94.value)+ parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C95.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C96.value) +  parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C97.value);
  
  CreativeAcquisitions.B101.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B4.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B105.value = (parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B101.value) * parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B103.value)) /100;
  CreativeAcquisitions.B107.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.C98.value);
  CreativeAcquisitions.B108.value = parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B101.value) + parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B105.value) - parseFloat(CreativeAcquisitions.B107.value);
}
```

```css
/* Style the form */
form {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #e6f9ff;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
}


table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;  
}

.tableRow {
  height: 30px;
  border-style: none;}

/* Rounded Valuation Sections */
.roundedValuation {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.roundedValuationInput {
  padding: 12px !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0 !important;
}


p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color:#e6f9ff;
    background-color: rgb(53,88,96);
    padding: 20px !important;
    margin: -20px !important;

}
h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #505050
}


h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.notes {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Style the total sum fields */
.total {
  padding: 10px !important;
  width: 150px !important;
  font-size: 17px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
 background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
}


/* Style the input fields no pound sign */
.noSign {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px !important;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}


/* Style the input fields step one */
.stepOne {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px !important;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}

/* Mark step one input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
.stepOne.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}


/* Style the input fields */
input {
  padding: 10px !important;
  margin-left: 10px !important;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 1px solid #F0F0F0 !important;
}


/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Mark the active step: */
.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

button {
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 120px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background:  rgb(53,88,96);
  color: #e6f9ff;
}

button:hover {
  background:  rgb(69,89,94);
}

/* Divi Theme Raltes Classes*/
.entry-content tr td, body.et-pb-preview #main-content .container tr td {
    border: none !important;
}

.entry-content table:not(.variations), body.et-pb-preview #main-content .container table {
    border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<form id="CreativeAcquisitions" action="">


  <div class="tab">
    <h2>STEP ONE</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Performance</h3>
    <p>What is the Adjusted Net Profit (or EBITDA)?</p>
    <input class="stepOne" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B4" value="200000">
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>What multiple would you like to apply? <span class="notes"> standard is from 2 to 3 (Preset value is 2) </span></p>
    <input class="noSign" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B6" value="2">
  </div>


  <div class="tab">
    <h2>STEP TWO</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Assets</h3>
    <h4>On the closing date</h4>
    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>How much Cash will be in the Bank account? <span class="notes"> (calculate 100%) </span> </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B17" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> How much in inventory will the business hold? <span class="notes"> (calculate 70%) </span></p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B19" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Please enter rough value of property owned by the business: <span class="notes"> (calculate 75%) </span> </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B21" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            Enter value of invoices that are outstanding (Receivables): <span class="notes"> (calculate 80%) </span></p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B23" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Enter value of other assets (like equipment and vehicles): <span class="notes"> (calculate 70%) </span></p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B25" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h5>
            Total </h5>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B28" value="50000"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>


  <div class="tab">
    <h2>STEP THREE</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Liabilities</h3>
    <h4>On the closing date</h4>
    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Enter value of outstanding Loans that the company has: </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B36" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            Enter approx. value of Corporation Tax outstanding: </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B37" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            Enter value of any money owed by the company (e.g to suppliers): </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B38" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            Is it possible to defer PAYE payments? If so how much </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B39" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            Is it possible to defer VAT payments? If so how much </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B40" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            Can you borrow money against the company (New loan for Acquisition)? <span class="notes"> (calculate 100%) </span> </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B41" value="120000"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tab">
    <h2>STEP FOUR</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Seller Equity & Deferred Payments</h3>
    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Is the Seller willing to hold back some equity in the business? If so, what percentage: </p>
        </td>
        <td>%<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B46" value="10"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> What percentage of the purchase price will the seller be willing to defer?</p>
        </td>
        <td>%<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B47" value="10"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div class="tab">
    <h2>RESULTS</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Valuation</h3>
    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>
            The value of the business is around: (TOTAL)</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B52" value="442500"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h4>This is broken down into:</h4>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Payment for Goodwill</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B55" value="400000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Payment for Assets</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B56" value="50000"></td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> Payment for Liabilities</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B68" value="50000"></td>
          </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p class="roundedValuation"> ENTER ROUNDED VALUATION</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="roundedValuationInput" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B200" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <h2>Deal Structure</h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h4>You can structure the deal in the following manner:</h4>


    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> VALUATION AMOUNT (Goodwill and Assets)</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B66" value="442500"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> MONEY POTENTIALLY RAISED FROM ALL ASSETS</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B67" value="50000"></td>
      
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>NEW LOAN RAISED</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B69" value="120000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>PAYMENT RETAINED FOR SELLER EQUITY SHARE</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B70" value="44250"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> SELLER DEFERRMENT AMOUNT</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B71" value="44250"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>SHORTFALL (SURPLUS)</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B72" value="184000"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <h2> Assets Valuation Breakdown</h2>
    <br>
    <br>


    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h5>Assets </h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Input Amount </h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Value </h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Net Value </h5>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Cash </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B76" value="10000"></td>
        <td>%<input type="number" min="1" max="100" onchange="calcule2()" name="C76" value="100"></td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D76" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> Inventory</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B77" value="10000"></td>
        <td>%<input type="number" min="1" max="100" onchange="calcule2()" name="C77" value="70"></td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D77" value="7000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> Property</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B78" value="10000"></td>
        <td>%<input type="number" min="1" max="100" onchange="calcule2()" name="C78" value="75"></td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D78" value="7500"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> Debitors</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B79" value="10000"></td>
        <td>%<input type="number" min="1" max="100" onchange="calcule2()" name="C79" value="80"></td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D79" value="8000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> Others</p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B80" value="10000"></td>
        <td>%<input type="number" min="1" max="100" onchange="calcule2()" name="C80" value="100"></td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D80" value="10000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h5> TOTAL</h5>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B81" value="50000"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="D81" value="42500"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>Cash Flow Calculator</h2>
    <br>
    <br>


    <table>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h5>LIABILITY </h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h5>Total Amount </h5>
        </td>
    
        <td>
          <h5>Yearly Repayment</h5>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Loan Repayment </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B91" value="10000"></td>
        
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C91" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Corporation Tax </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B92" value="10000"></td>
       
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C92" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Trade Creditors </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B93" value="10000"></td>
        
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C93" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>PAYE Deferments </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B94" value="10000"></td>
       
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C94" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p> VAT Deferments </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B95" value="10000"></td>
      
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C95" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>Seller Deferred Payment </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B96" value="44250"></td>
     
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C96" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <p>New Loan taken </p>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B97" value="120000"></td>
       
        <td>£<input type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C97" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h5> TOTAL </h5>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B98" value="214250"></td>

        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="C98" value="0"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
    <br>
    <h2>SUMMARY</h2>
    <br>
    <br>

    <table table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h4>Net Profit </h4>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B101" value="200000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h4>CT RATE <span class="notes"> (Pre-set at 19%) </span> </h4>
        </td>
        <td>%<input type="number" min="1" max="100" onchange="calcule2()" name="B103" value="19"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h4>CT DUE IN FUTURE : </h4>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B105" value="38000"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h4>COST OF PAYING LIABILITIES</h4>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B107" value="42850"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tableRow">
        <td>
          <h4>CASH FLOW SURPLUS PER YEAR <span class="notes"> (Post financing and tax) </span></h4>
        </td>
        <td>£<input class="total" type="text" onchange="calcule2()" name="B108" value="195150"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div>
    <div class="right">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how can I apply this code in my case (please check the JSFIDDLE link) thanks a million

Comment: Ok I took a look on your fiddle post, you don't need to deal with negative numbers nor with floating points, so I changed the function to be as simple as it needs to be, and added some code to solve your problem.

Comment: I really THANK YOU SOO MUCH. One last question if I may? Everything looks good but I have noticed that the SUMS (or any field that has calculations on it) is not working. Is it because it's treating them as strings? any work arounds?

Comment: Well I didn't see the attribue onchange event listeners in your HTML, so I should have used addEventListener instead of replacing your listeners, but even doing that need the parseFloat will see the value as floating point instead, so 20.000 will be 20 so incorrect calculations, I have changed my code to deal with the problem but because of your repeated code, I had to write a repeated code too :(, note that now no onchange attribute listener is needed, you can delete them.

Comment: Perfect... Thank you so much... I really appreciate all your efforts... Best of luck my friend :-)

Comment: @Moeadas you should accept this answer as correct, it will help people who have same doubt.